# Statistical data on global software development industry / market size

Tags: data-request, software

Where can I find statistical data related to the evolution of the global software development market? I'm looking for data related to the evolution of at least one of the following:

- the number of software professionals in the world
- global software spending
- global software development companies revenue
- number of software development companies

I need data for at least 20 years. I’ll be using the data for a research I’m conducting in a PhD program.